# Enable/Disable Textblock in a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a `ContextMenu` with a `MenuItem` inside it. The `MenuItem` is a `TextBlock` as shown in the below code:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <Border>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="ACK" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </Border>
</ContextMenu>
```

How do I enable or disable it at runtime. If I click it once, it should be disabled.

PS: I don't want to write code-behind for this. I need to achieve it from the XAML as this is done in a `UserControl` and is going to be used in many applications.

Comment: What about using triggers?

Comment: There's a stigma that code-behind is bad, this is untrue. There's nothing wrong with doing **view code** in the code-behind.

Comment: Your `UserControl` will be in a library (presumably), and that library can include code-behind code as well as the XAML for the control. That you are going to use it _"in many applications"_ in no way suggests that code-behind should not or cannot be used. As for the specific question, your `TextBlock.IsEnabled` property should be bound to some view model where you can control the state (i.e. set to `false` when desired, such as when the menu item is used).

Comment: There are many possible solutions to the basic requirement; please try _something_ provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried, and a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: you guys are correct @MikeEason and Peter but that's the clients requirement that there should be minimal code behind :(
I am giving it a try by using Styles.
I have defined a style in a resources file and calling the style at the TextBlock but that too isnt working.(This had worked in the previous project which I did)